# How to authenticate with a Google Service Account in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: authentication, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, credentials, gcloud

I want to use `gcloud` in Jenkins pipeline and therefore I have to authenticate first with the Google Service account. I'm using the https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Google+OAuth+Plugin which holds my Private Key Credentials. I'm stuck with loading the credentials into the pipeline:

```
withCredentials([[$class: 'MultiBinding', credentialsId: 'my-creds', variable: 'GCSKEY']]) {
    sh "gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=${GCSKEY}"
}
```

I also tried it with from file, but without luck.

```
withCredentials([file(credentialsId:'my-creds', variable: 'GCSKEY')]) {
```

The log says:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.credentialsbinding.impl.CredentialNotFoundException: Credentials 'my-creds' is of type 'Google Service Account from private key' ....
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You need to upload your Sevice Account JSON file as a **secret file**.
Then:

```
withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'key-sa', variable: 'GC_KEY')]) {
    sh("gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=${GC_KEY}")
    sh("gcloud container clusters get-credentials prod --zone northamerica-northeast1-a --project ${project}")
  }
```

Comment: Why can't I upvote every time I read this? @stackoverflow plz

Comment: Please make it **bolder and clearer** that JSON file should be uploaded as a secret file and not as a google service account

Comment: it works to me too, but I should use. '${GC_KEY}' .

Comment: I got this: ERROR: (gcloud.auth.activate-service-account) There was a problem refreshing your current auth tokens: ('invalid_grant: Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values in the JWT claim.',

Comment: 2 errors :  'StringCredentials' was expected, 'FileCredentials' was expected, with same config u have

Comment: How do you upload it as a secret file? i did upload it with the Jenkins Plugin, and getting this error - type 'Google Service Account from private key' where 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.FileCredentials

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't get the 'Google Service Account from private key' working, but using the 'Secret File' type of credential in Jenkins, and uploaded my google service account JSON works.