# Login as GCP SA-developer impersonator account in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

We can connect to GCP services secret manager or PubSub by logging as sa-developer impersonator account while running the application in local.

```
gcloud auth application-default login --impersonate-service-account sa-developer@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

This will open the for google cloud in default browser and store the credentials in `application_default_credentials.json` and used by `ADC`

What is the approach to do the similar mechanism in Jenkins? OR is there any way to connect to GCP services like secret manager using vault service account.

Comment: Where is your Jenkin Setup is it inside the GCP cluster or some were else?

Comment: Your example is using `user` credentials to then impersonate a service account. That requires a web browser to first authenticate the user. See this answer for how to use a service account in Jenkins: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51367104/8016720